# Get users of project

Tags: rally

How do I get users (not team members) of a given project using Ruby Rally Toolkit? I am trying to run a query to change the roles of all the users in a given project to "Editor", for that I need to get the list of all users of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to get the list of all Users with ProjectPermissions in a Project. This endpoint:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678910/Editors`

Will obtain a list of all *Editors* in a Project. However that doesn't help very much if you want to promote any Viewers in a Project to Editors - and there's no such collection as:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678910/Viewers`

or

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678910/Users`

Although it would makes sense and be kind of nice if there were.

Unfortunately your only recourse is to query through all Users and their UserPermissions in your Ruby code, examine their ProjectPermissions, and operate on anyone having ProjectPermission.Role = Viewer for the Project of interest. Sorry there's not a better way, at least that I know of.

Comment: I am currently getting all users and for each record, looking at the UserPermissions, if the collection contains the given project name that means he is the user of that project.